# For loop and for of loops not showing array value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array like this:

```
let arr = ["zero", "one", "two"]; // I'm an indexed array!
arr.foo = "bar";
```

If I try accessing arr.foo, it's accessible:

```
console.log(arr.foo); // Returns "bar"
```

However, if I loop over this array with *for loop* like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${i} => ${arr[i]}`);
}
```

I get this:

```
0 => zero
1 => one
2 => two
3 => undefined
```

Also, if I use *for in loop* like this:

```
for (let y in arr) {
  console.log(y);
}
```

I get indexes, including foo:

```
0
1
2
foo
```

But if I use *for of* like this:

```
for (let z of arr) {
  console.log(z);
}
```

I get this:

```
zero
one
two
```

So foo value is missing in both *for* and *for of* loops!

Question is, why is foo inaccessible inside of these loops? Why does it say its *undefined*, when I can access it using arr.foo?

Comment: JavaScript is a loose and permissive dynamically typed language. Arrays are Objects and so you can set properties on them. However properties like `.foo` set on an Array are not _enumerable_ (by default) and so you will not see them when using a `for` loop.

Comment: [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration). You shouldn't use `for/in` for arrays. And what @Mulan said.

Comment: While I'm probably not the best to describe the inner mechanics of how iteration works in js, [check out this article](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) on how arrays are a myth! Really Arrays are just objects, and when you add a string as a key, iteration seems to struggle a bit, however the `in` keyword will still give you all the keys. There will also be a length reflecting the number of values. The `of` loop may have some logic looking for the next index, and ending if none are found.

Comment: @Andy I did both for in and for of, and same happens.

Comment: What do you get with `Object.entries( arr )`?

Comment: i < arr.length.